# Problema con orientación de pagina PDF con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, itextsharp

Estoy comenzando a utilizar la librería de **iTextSharp** para generar **PDF** desde código **C#** estoy tratando con los ejemplos que he encontrado en Internet y no doy que falla.

Esto es como lo estoy intentando:

```
        string path = @"C:\PruebaPDF\Test.pdf";
        var PDF = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        PDF.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());            
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDF, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
        PDF.AddTitle("Reporte");
        PDF.AddAuthor("Yo");
        PDF.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph Titulo = new Paragraph("Reporte Mensual de Consultoría");
        Titulo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //Titulo.IndentationLeft = 100;  //Darle ubicación por desplazamiento izquierdo
        //Titulo.IndentationRight = 100; //Darle ubicación por desplazamiento derecho
        Paragraph text1 = new Paragraph("Tipo");
        PDF.Add(Titulo);
        PDF.Add(text1);
        PDF.Close();
        writer.Close();
```

Con esto, me sigue mandando la pagina en vertical. ¿Qué me puede estar faltando?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta colocandolo en el constructor, y elimina la tercera linea coloca :

```
var PDF = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Y elimina :

```
PDF.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
```

Comment: Ya había intentado eso, desde el constructor y me lo cambia, pero si quisiera que fuera para determinada pagina ?¿

Comment: Si rotas el documento antes de entrar a la pagina que deseas rotar : PDF.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate()); y despues antes de salir de la pagina la vuelves a dejar como estaba.